# reload tableview in masterviewcontroller when make changes in detailsviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisplitview

I'm playing with split view and want to reload the table in master view when I make some changes in detail view.

I do a callback to masterview to reload data:

in detailview:

```
- (void) doneEditSite {
    [popCtrl dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [editSiteVC release];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    masterVC *tableList = [[masterVC alloc] init];
    [tableList refreshMV:nil];
    [tableList release];
}
```

in masterVC:

```
- (void) refreshMV:(id)sender {
    [self getAllMySite:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection are called (I've checked it with a NSLog) but the cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called.

What I'm missing?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not `alloc/init` an new master view but get a reference to existing one.

Comment: You're right but I haven't an existing reference. Anyway I solved with notifier. Thanks,